# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, command line making problem and bash scripting

Tags: java, bash, scripting, classnotfoundexception

I'm new to bash scripting and cannot find a fix suitable and that I can understand on the web. The problem seems classical but I lost.

I try to make my own command lines I can use directly from a bash terminal on Ubuntu. I use an alternative .bash_profile to make sure to avoid problems with the .bashsr file containing the default bash environment settings. I load my settings with `source .bash_profile`

I then have my own /bin_onyr directory where I put the .sh scripts in order to make my own commands as well as a script with aliases I want to use and access permissions to the other scripts.

Problem, I get this :

> onyr@kenzae:~$ source .bash_profile  Welcome Onyr. Pleased to see you
>   again. ʘ gameoflife 10 12 15 Error: Could not find or load main class
>   GameOfLife.class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   GameOfLife.class

I want to transform my java program GameOfLife.class as a command line I can use directly. The program works with and without passed arguments.

```
onyr@kenzae:~$ cd Documents/computer_sciences/tp_java/10_tp_game_of_life/
onyr@kenzae:~/Documents/computer_sciences/tp_java/10_tp_game_of_life$ java GameOfLife
frameNumber0 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  X  .  .  X  .  X  X  .  X  .  . 
 .  .  .  X  .  .  .  .  .  .  X  . 
 .  X  X  X  .  .  .  .  X  .  .  . 
 .  X  .  .  .  X  X  .  .  .  X  . 
 .  X  X  X  .  .  X  X  .  X  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

I don't know what to do. Bellow are my scripts. Please help :

.bash_profile in /home/onyr

```
#This is a personal alternative to the original .bashrc environment settings
echo "Welcome Onyr. Pleased to see you again."
export PS1="ʘ "
#get the aliases for personnal commands
chmod +x ./bin_onyr/bash_aliases_onyr.sh #grant run permission
source ./bin_onyr/bash_aliases_onyr.sh
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/$
#test
alias greet3="~/bin_onyr/greetings_codecademy.sh 3"
```

bash_aliases_onyr in /home/onyr/bin_onyr

```
#!/bin/bash
#grant run permission for shell command line bash files
chmod +x ~/bin_onyr/greetings_codecademy.sh
chmod +x ~/bin_onyr/gameoflife.sh
# This file contains my own command aliases
alias greet3="~/bin_onyr/greetings_codecademy.sh 3" #3 is default value
alias greet="~/bin_onyr/greetings_codecademy.sh" #here there must be an agrument ex: greet 4
alias gameoflife="~/bin_onyr/gameoflife.sh" #the game of life displayed
```

gameoflife.sh in /home/onyr/bin_onyr

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/onyr/Documents/computer_sciences/tp_java/10_tp_game_of_life/
java GameOfLife.class $@
```

GameOfLife.class is located in a different directory /home/onyr/Documents/computer_sciences/tp_java/10_tp_game_of_life/

Comment: Try changing your batch script to `java GameOfLife` (without .class)

Comment: Problem solved, thank you